# Крутящийся спиннер при перезагрузке страницы. Как реализовать?

Tags: css3

Нужно в процессе загрузки страницы поставить крутящийся спиннер.

Поставил гифку, но она, видимо, не успевает загрузиться и висит просто первый статичный кадр.

А, вот например, тут [клик](https://my.med-service.com.ua)

все красиво.

Как такое реализуется? К своему стыду впервые с этим столкнулся.

Comment: глянь сюда http://freefrontend.com/css-loaders/ А потом можно при помощи JS сделать так что бы при релоад сначала отображался лоадер

Comment: Что-то не удалось запустить. Интересует круг-догонялка - https://codepen.io/animatedcreativity/pen/OjBPQJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ничего сложного, это CSS анимация

```css
#page-preloader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #00a5f1;
  z-index: 100500;
}

#page-preloader .spinner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;

  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; 
  border-top: 16px solid rgba(0,0,0, .5); 
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div id="page-preloader" style="background: red;">
        <span class="spinner"></span>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.circle {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border:8px solid red;
  border-top:8px solid green;
  border-radius:50%;
  animation: rotate 2s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```